# Is it possible to make all database interaction within an app limited to read?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, locking

I have an existing Laravel application with various functions, controllers, authentication, middleware, CRUD, admin functionality, and more.  I want to be able to deploy this application onto some hosting and have others view all of the pages, but I do not want them to be able to edit or create values in the database. So, for example, while I have CRUD for all of the resources, I want them to be able to read all of the resources but not edit, create, or delete anything.  I also want them to not have to register/login, but I know how to fix that.

I have tried `LOCK TABLE [tablename] READ` in MySQL, but that does not seem to have done anything.  Currently, my only other idea would be to go through and set ifs checking if the user is authenticated to save database interactions, but this would be a little laborious.

Is there any feasible or simpler way of doing this?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not grant the `DB_USER` in your `.env` read priveleges only?

Comment: Oh wow.  Yeah, that makes way more sense.  I'd still like to have those permissions for myself, but it's obviously not essential as I can access it directly.  Thanks.